# Access insists on saving queries

Tags: ms-access

More of an annoyance than anything else, but I couldn't find any information on it in Google.

I'll often create a query in Access 2007 to test something, or quickly grab some results on a one time basis. I don't want to save these queries, as they're only good for one use.

Not always, but often, Access won't close this query without me saving it, which then means I have to later delete it. This can prevent me from closing Access until I've saved it, and creates a derth of unwanted queries.

Why is this happening? Is there something in particular that sets it off?

Comment: I've never come across this, and I do the same all the time. Do you have any add-ins installed ?

Comment: I had that sometimes in previous versions of Access. I found that it had something to do with a setting called "auto save objects" (or similar).

Comment: If your Access settings include "Track name AutoCorrect" on, switch it off and see whether that makes any difference.

Comment: @HansUp - wouldn't that stop it auto-correcting table/query names within other queries if I change them though?

Comment: Yes, it would.  I offered that WAG suggestion to track down the reason Access insists you save a new query instead of simply discarding it.  I've never seen that happen.  And I couldn't find the setting Cristoph mentioned.  But track name autocorrect has side effects which Allen Browne describes on his site.  So I was speculating the behavior you're seeing is a side effect.  But it's only speculation.  If it does prove to be the culprit, you would then have to decide which course of action is less frustrating for you.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, everyone. @HansUp feel free to add yours as an answer, then I can select it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `Track name AutoCorrect info` path was not what did it for me. Rather it turns out I had left `DoCmd.SetWarnings False` set. Going into the immediate window and running `DoCmd.SetWarnings True` brought back the old "Do you want to save this query Yes/No/Cancel" window.

Comment: Well I'll be a .....  I know it's been sitting here since 2013, but I've never bothered looking further into this problem.  I've just muttered under my breath, called Access a few choice words, saved the query and deleted it. A late +1 for you. :)

Comment: So helpful!  <slap forehead>  This makes perfect sense, but sure is easy to miss.

Answer (score 4):

If you have turned off warnings in VBA (`DoCmd.SetWarnings False`) but haven't turned them on later, you'll get this behavior every time. Remember that:

1. You should always turn warnings on when you're finished with a procedure
2. If you error out of a procedure that has turned warnings off, they're probably still off.

Try going into VBA, call up the Immediate window (`Ctrl+G`), type in `DoCmd.SetWarnings True` and hit `Enter`.

Answer (score 3):

As a wild guess, I'll suggest you check whether *Track Name AutoCorrect* is causing the behavior you described.  If it is enabled, disable it temporarily and see if Access still forces you to save new queries instead of simply discarding them.

The reason I offer this suggestion is because I've never seen that behavior.  Whenever I attempt to close a new unsaved query, Access asks me whether I want to save the query design, and just discards the unsaved query when I respond "No".

And I never leave *Track Name AutoCorrect* enabled because it's reported to create too many problems ([Flaws in Microsoft Access: Problem properties](http://allenbrowne.com/bug-09.html) and [Failures caused by Name AutoCorrect](http://allenbrowne.com/bug-03.html)).  Of course this may just be a coincidence, but I think it could be worthwhile to check whether autocorrect is involved.

And if *Track Name AutoCorrect* is the cause, you would then need to decide which is less painful: leave *Track Name AutoCorrect* disabled permanently; or be forced to save new queries you don't want to keep.

Answer (score 2):

Weird one this.. I too had exactly the same problem whereby i was only give the option to Save or Cancel the query. Found this thread and checked the Track Name AutoCorrect and it was set to Off.... turned it on, then cancelled out when it said it wanted to map the database and hey presto my query dialog changed to Do you want to save, Yes No or Cancel.. so you may only need to click on/off to reset this "feature"