# Access 2010 how to I clear SubForm after a new record is add (VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I was just wondering if there is any way to clear subform after I click the button Send in VBA (Access 2010). I am able to clear the textbox and the cbox by using SetProperty
[image]

Comment: What are the data in that subform? How did it get in there and how is it bound to the parent form?

Comment: I am maintaining a legacy vba system right now and the previous dev used subforms like this and it was a pain in the butt to work with. I replaced them with listboxes and not only does it look neater, it is far easier to just do a clear and rebuild whenever an update needs to occur. Just my thoughts on another approach you can use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just delete the contents of the table the subform is bound to :)

Part of your "Send" button can have this line of code

```
"DoCmd.RunSql "DELETE * FROM mytbl"
```

Comment: I'd suggest not using `DoCmd.RunSql` becauseit pops up a dialog asking if you really want to delete those records. And to get around that you need to disable warning and that is a whole can of worms. Much easier to instead use `CurrentDb.Execute` to do the same thing.

Comment: Im confused how something as standard as DoCmd.SetWarnings false and then setting it to true is a can of worms, but hey whatever. same end results :)

Comment: While common it's not good practice.The fact that MS let's you shoot yourself in the foot with it is annoying enough. If you forget to unset it, if there is an error and you don't get the change to set it back. Either of these scenarios leave your DB doing really weird things down the road. It is particularly easy to avoid do you may as well not even put yourself in that situation.

Comment: While we'll agree to disagree, however, UI testing, Error Handling and UI Flow are a thing. Specifically Error Handling.

Comment: In addition to needing 3 lines as opposed to 1 to do the same thing here's an example of what can go (very confusingly) wrong. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15761959/access-2007-inists-on-saving-queries

Comment: Sounds like a rookie mistake if you ask me. immediate window + ? DoCmd.SetWarnings True is a thing....

Comment: If you start littering your code with these and you have multiple people working on it these things happen. Easiest solution is to just not put yourself in that situation ever. Plus `CurrentDb.Execute` can execute saved queries which `RunSql` cannot do. I don't see why you would want to write more lines of code that are more fragile and less flexible?

Comment: IDK do you think saving simple queries as queries makes more sense? Or is it actually easier to write inline SQL like this? Youre now going to start arguing best practices with style preference, which seems like you've confused the two. Working in an environment with multiple access developers, this has yet to be an issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146707/discussion-between-brad-and-doug-coats).

Comment: @Brad It might not be tonight but i would be glad to let you tell me at another point your approach :)